# Registration form labels - add asterisk

Tags: forms, user-registration

Is there an easy way to add a required symbol like '*' *after* the html `<label>` text content in the default user registration form?

I'd like the Username and E-mail labels to display: Username * and Email *

I've tried using CSS, as in:

`#registerform p label::after {
    content:" *";
    color: red;
}`

But the asterisk appears *under* the text field, not beside the text.

I checked the Codex but couldn't find a WP filter, so does this mean I need to create an entirely custom registration form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * appears under the field because the field is inside the label. There doesn't appear to be any useful filters for this, but you could use one of the hooks to inject some JS on the page that adds the *:

```
required = jQuery( "<span>*</span>" );
required.css("color", "red");
jQuery('label br').before( required );
```

Note: if you're going to use a library like jQuery in my example, you'll need to queue that as well - it's not by default on the register page

Comment: Thanks! That works really well. Only issue - it applies to *every* field and I have some custom non-required. Is it possible to target with something like this:
`jQuery( 'label[for="user_login"] br').before( required );
jQuery( 'label[for="user_email"] br').before( required );`

Comment: In the above, only the second one will work. But if you remove it, the first one will work.

Comment: I put the labels in an array ( var the_labels = ["user_login", "user_email", "first_name", "last_name"];  ) and looped through it with `for` creating a unique "required" for each label ( so required1, required2, etc.) That did it. Thanks, @karpstrucking