# How can I modify labels in default wordpress registration form?

Tags: forms, user-registration

I need to change Label text in registration form, especially "Email" label. I want to add asterisk or just add text "required field"
How can I do that? Please advice...

Comment: This solution helps me to solve my issue - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175128/registration-form-labels-add-asterisk?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using default WordPress registration form. But there are no "Email" field. OK but you can try below code.

```
if ($pagenow=='wp-login.php') { 
   add_filter( 'gettext', 'user_email_login_text', 20, 3 );
      function user_email_login_text( $translated_text, $text, $domain ){
          if ($translated_text == 'Email') {
               $translated_text = 'Email required field';
          }

          return $translated_text;
     }
}
```